# DotNetHighcharts & C#: How do I Load a multidimensional object array?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, dotnethighcharts

I'm trying to create a dotnet highcharts in C#. If you're familiar with dotnot highcharts then you're aware that the datasource must be an Object. My data will be coming in from SQL Server. When I initially started creating this I created a class to load the SQL data into:

```
public class chartDataByGradeByGenderByRace
{
    public string locID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public decimal y { get; set; }
    public int tot { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
    public chartDrillDown drilldown { get; set; }
}

public class chartDrillDown
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<string> categories { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> data { get; set; }
    public List<int> totCat { get; set; }
}
```

My function that loads the data into the class:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public List<chartDataByGradeByGenderByRace> getChartDataByGradeByGender(string gender, int pageID)
    {
        formValues fv = new formValues();
        string personID = fv.personID;

        List<chartDataByGradeByGenderByRace> ls = new List<chartDataByGradeByGenderByRace>();
        object ao = new chartDataByGradeByGenderByRace();

        string mySQL = "exec get_referralPct_byGrade_byGender_byRace @personID, @pageID, @Gender";
        string cf = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DistrictAssessmentDWConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cf);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(mySQL, connection);

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@personID", personID);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pageID", pageID);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", gender);

        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

        string name = null;
        chartDataByGradeByGenderByRace cd = new chartDataByGradeByGenderByRace();
        chartDrillDown cdd = new chartDrillDown();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (name != dr["name"].ToString())
            {
                if (name != null)
                {
                    cd.drilldown = cdd;

                    ls.Add(cd);
                }

                cd = new chartDataByGradeByGenderByRace();
                cd.drilldown = new chartDrillDown();
                name = dr["name"].ToString();

                cd.y = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["y"]);
                cd.tot = Convert.ToInt32(dr["tot"]);
                cdd = new chartDrillDown();
                cdd.categories = new List<string>();
                cdd.data = new List<decimal>();
                cdd.totCat = new List<int>();
                cdd.name = dr["name"].ToString();
            }

            cdd.categories.Add(dr["categories"].ToString());
            cdd.data.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(dr["data"]));
            cdd.totCat.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr["totCat"]));
        }

        connection.Close();

        cd.drilldown = cdd;
        ls.Add(cd);

        return ls;
    }
```

And my method that builds the dotnet highcharts:

```
    protected void getGradeGenderChart()
    {
        refData rd = new refData();
        List<chartCategoriesGrade> cats = new List<chartCategoriesGrade>();
        List<chartDataByGradeByGenderByRace> male = new List<chartDataByGradeByGenderByRace>();
        List<chartDataByGradeByGenderByRace> female = new List<chartDataByGradeByGenderByRace>();

        string locID = schoolArea.Replace("%", "D") + schoolLevel.Replace("%", "L") + schoolID_alt.Replace("%", "S");
        string id = "refsGradeGender" + locID;

        cats = rd.getChartCategories_Grade(29, "html");
        male = rd.getChartDataByGradeByGender("Male", 29);
        female = rd.getChartDataByGradeByGender("Female", 29);

        string[] catObject = new string[cats.Count];
        int idx = 0;
        foreach (chartCategoriesGrade cat in cats)
        {
            catObject[idx++] = cat.grade;
        }

        DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts(id)
            .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Column, Height = 225 })
            .SetTitle(new Title
            {
                Text = "Grade/Gender (Click columns to view Races)",
            })
            .SetYAxis(new YAxis
            {
                Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "% of Referrals" },
                Labels = new YAxisLabels { Enabled = false },
                GridLineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent
            })
            .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = catObject })
            .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
            {
                Column = new PlotOptionsColumn
                {
                    DataLabels = new PlotOptionsColumnDataLabels
                    {
                        Enabled = true,
                        Formatter = "function() { return this.y; }",
                        Style = "fontWeight: 'bold'"
                    }
                },
                Series = new PlotOptionsSeries
                {
                    Cursor = Cursors.Pointer,
                    Point = new PlotOptionsSeriesPoint
                    {
                        Events = new PlotOptionsSeriesPointEvents { Click = "function() { location.href = this.options.url; }" }
                    }
                }
            })
            .SetSeries(new[] {
                new Series { Name= "Males", Data = new Data(male.ToArray()) },
                new Series { Name = "Females", Data = new Data(female.ToArray()) }
            })
            .SetLegend(new Legend { 
                Align = HorizontalAligns.Left,
                Floating = true,
                Layout = Layouts.Vertical,
                Padding = 2,
                VerticalAlign = VerticalAligns.Top
                })
            .SetCredits(new Credits { Enabled = false });

        refsByGradeByGenderByRace.Text = chart.ToHtmlString();
    }
```

When I run this, I get the following error on the final line of code: **Parameter count mismatch**.

I've played around and know the error is caused by the .SetSeries section of code, using the male.ToArray() function. I've created dotnet highcharts before using this method, but in those cases the class being converted did not have a subclass. I don't know if the issue is that using ToArray() isn't converting the subclass to an object or what.

So as I see it, I have two options: 1) Just load the SQL data into an Object array at the very beginning and pass that over or 2) convert the class into a multidimensional object and use that in the .Set Series section.  Unfortunately, I'm at a loss on how to do either.  All the examples I've read just deal with very simple arrays, but nothing I've found shows how to create an array with different values, how to create the names for those values, how to do the multidimensional part, etc. etc.

I would be so, so grateful if somebody could teach me how to fish on this one :(

Comment: What is your desired behavior? How many lines are you expecting to see?

Comment: This is for schools in a district and will show the break down of Male & Female suspensions by race, so it varies by school, but usually displays about 8-12 columns/lines of data.  I've used the same template above to create simpler dotnethighcharts, and while playing around, this one works if I comment out the "Drilldown" portion of the class and just fill in the top-level of the class.